# Reading CSV containing emojis from Google Sheets fails

Tags: r, google-sheets, encoding, windows-10, emoji

I've made a survey on Google Forms and send results to Google Sheets.

Then I tried to download results to R:

```
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRkkjx8AOgNdfDW9wtaHR8wtMQOrgTB1O1wwMcJLGre3E_MixhEaIGUI7gfHw5gBQX7-gcNkRUkMM3X/pub?output=csv'

google <- read.csv(url, sep = ',',  header = T, fileEncoding = "UTF-8")
```

and faced the problem:

```
Warning:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  incorrect input found in input connection 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRkkjx8AOgNdfDW9wtaHR8wtMQOrgTB1O1wwMcJLGre3E_MixhEaIGUI7gfHw5gBQX7-gcNkRUkMM3X/pub?output=csv'
```

There were imported just 96 rows out of all to my R dataset.

I checked my Google Sheets and saw that 96th row contains emoji and stops downloading another rows.
What should I do there or which encoding should I choose to have an opprotuninty to read the emojis in R?

R version: 1.2.5033

Comment: The R version doesn't look right. Are you sure that is not your RStudio version? Also there is a package for reading data from Google sheets: https://googlesheets4.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Yes, it's RStudio's version. But 'googlesheets4' package is requesting access to my Google account. I don't want to share my acc info.

Comment: I can’t reproduce your problem, it works for me. Which OS are you using?

Comment: @KonradRudolph Windows 10

Comment: Then this is almost certainly a bug in R’s handling of Unicode on Windows.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I think so too, my friend downloads this Sheet without any problems in encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to load the contents of the file as a character vector then remove the emojis manually before you load the data.

Removing the very high UTF-8 values is a crude but effective way of stripping out emojis.

```r
remove_emojis <- function(strings)
{
  sapply(strings, function(x) intToUtf8(utf8ToInt(x)[-which(utf8ToInt(x) > 100000)]))
}

google <- remove_emojis(readLines(url, encoding = "UTF-8"))
df     <- read.table(text = google,
                     sep = ",", 
                     fileEncoding = "UTF-8", 
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: It works for me as well, but what if I have more rows with emojis in Sheet?

Comment: it takes rows with emojis from Sheet, but I need all my rows)

Comment: @RomanLukonin no, it only removes the emojis. It converts each row from a single string of characters to a vector of integers, then removes the integers that are emojis, then converts back to a string. The rows are not affected.

Comment: But when I write View(df), it shows me just 3 rows where emojis have been before, but without them.

Comment: I've found new decision, thank you, Allan! I can't give a mark to your answer because I don't have enough reputation to do it(

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Allan, you helped a lot to me!

I found another decision.

```
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRkkjx8AOgNdfDW9wtaHR8wtMQOrgTB1O1wwMcJLGre3E_MixhEaIGUI7gfHw5gBQX7-gcNkRUkMM3X/pub?output=csv'
df = readLines(url, encoding = "UTF-8")
df     <- read.table(text = df,
                     sep = ",", 
                     fileEncoding = "UTF-8", 
                     stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Then I used View function to check my rows with emojis, and it shows it to me correctly.